# vue 3 composition api : Missing return type on function

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

i have a composable like below and the editor says:

Type '{ menuItems: ComputedRef<menuItem[]>; }' is not assignable to type 'menuItem[]'.

```
import { computed } from "vue";

interface menuItem {
  title: string;
  link: string;
  icon: string;
}

export default (): menuItem[] => {
  const menuItems = computed<menuItem []>(() => [
    {
      title: "کاربران",
      link: "/users",
      icon: "users",
    },
    {
      title: "مجموعه ها",
      link: "/collections",
      icon: "users",
    },
    {
      title: "آیتم ها",
      link: "/items",
      icon: "users",
    },
    {
      title: "نظرات",
      link: "/comments",
      icon: "users",
    },
    {
      title: "دسته ها",
      link: "/categories",
      icon: "categories",
    },
  ]);

  return {
    menuItems,
  };
};
```

what sholud i say as the returned value of the default exported funciton

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Answer (score 1):

The error spells it out for you:

> Type '{ menuItems: ComputedRef<menuItem[]>; }' is not assignable to type 'menuItem[]'.

The compiler is inferring a return type of `{ menuItems: ComputedRef<menuItem[]>; }`, but you are explicitly telling it that the return type is `menuItem[]`.

You can either add the correct return type:

```
import { computed, ComputedRef } from "vue";

interface menuItem {
  title: string;
  link: string;
  icon: string;
}

export default (): { menuItems: ComputedRef <menuItem[]> } => {
  const menuItems = computed<menuItem []>(() => [
    {
      title: "کاربران",
      link: "/users",
      icon: "users",
    },
  ]);

  return {
    menuItems,
  };
};
```

or remove the function's return type and rely on typescript inference.